# Eulerian Tour in Python

Tags: python, graph

This is a recursive algorithm implementation of Eulerian tour search.

I guess there is no way to make it more efficient (except rewriting with loops instead of recursion). Any advice on style?

```
def sub(visited, _cur, graph):
    if not graph:
        return visited + [_cur]
    for i, edge in enumerate(graph):
        cur, nex = edge
        if _cur not in edge:
            continue
        _graph = graph[:]
        del _graph[i]
        if _cur == cur:
            res = sub(visited + [cur], nex, _graph)
        else:
            res = sub(visited + [nex], cur, _graph)
        if res:
            return res


def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    head, tail = graph[0], graph[1:]
    prev, nex = head
    return sub([prev], nex, tail)

assert find_eulerian_tour([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
assert find_eulerian_tour([
    (0, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7), (4, 5),
    (4, 8), (1, 6), (3, 7), (5, 9),
    (2, 4), (0, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6),
    (8, 9)
]) == [0, 1, 7, 3, 6, 1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 5, 2, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Comments and good [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) would go a long way. Obviously if I was familiar with the algorithm I'd understand easier, but you're not helping a lot with your naming. Why are you using `_cur` and `cur`? Do you just want to use the same name twice without clashing? If so you should do it another way, because `_var` is the Python style of indicating a variable that should be treated as private and not modified externally. It's an idiom for classes and looks out of place here.

Even still, `cur`, `nex` mean `current` and `next`, right? As you noted you shouldn't use `next` because it's a builtin name, but using `next_branch` or something more descriptive is better than stripping away a letter. Also if I've got the wrong end of the stick and `nex` is something else, that also just means you need a better shortened word or a comment explaining what `nex` is.

Also more whitespace will make the flow of your code easier to read than a solid block of text:

```
def sub(visited, _cur, graph):
    if not graph:
        return visited + [_cur]

    for i, edge in enumerate(graph):
        cur, nex = edge
        if _cur not in edge:
            continue

        _graph = graph[:]
        del _graph[i]

        if _cur == cur:
            res = sub(visited + [cur], nex, _graph)
        else:
            res = sub(visited + [nex], cur, _graph)

        if res:
            return res
```

Even before adding code and more readable names, this breaks up what's happening so a reader can parse it easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_euler_tour(visited,current,graph):
    queue=[current]
    while queue:
        if graph[current]:
            queue.append(current) 
            current=graph[current].pop()
        else:
            visited.append(current)
            current=queue.pop()

    return
```

Thanks, changed your code to get rid of the recursive part, and I am using adjacency graphs (which have 2n edges) . Also you rebooted your graph matrix at every step, and I knew mine had 10000ish edges so, this way I am just slowly eating away at smaller lists inside of a dictionary of children vertices connected to parent vertices (adjacency graph).

Graph was created like this: assumming a 2-tuple for each edge between node A,B

```
from collections import defaultdict
graph=defaultdict(list)
for A,B in edges:
    graph[A].append(B)
    graph[B].append(A)
```

Called like

```
visited=[]
current=1   #starting at Node 1 for example
find_euler_tour(visited,current,graph)
```

I was after a complete n-ary tree eulerian walk through a undirected tree graph. First step toward Least Common Ancestor.